# How do I convert numeric value into hours and minutes depending upon the number of digits

Tags: r, datetime-conversion

I have a vector which contains the time of nearest half an hour

```
x <- c(30,200,2200,2300)
```

I need to convert this into

```
output <- c(00:30,02:00,22:00,23:00).
```

I am not able to convert the values which are less than 4 digits.
Please suggest. `strptime()` , `as.Date()` throws `NA` for the first element.

I tried with the below Code and it did not work. Please suggest

Code:

```
x <- c(30,200,2200,2300)

output <- format(strptime(x,"%H%M"),"%H:%M")
output
#[1] NA      "20:00" "22:00" "23:00"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet another way using `formatC`

```
x <- c(30, 200, 2200, 2300)
formatC(x, width = 4, flag = "0", big.mark = ":", big.interval = 2)
#[1] "00:30" "02:00" "22:00" "23:00"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sprintf`, to add leading zeros.

```
x <- c(30, 200, 2200, 2300)
format(strptime(sprintf("%04d", x), format="%H%M"), format="%H:%M")
# [1] "00:30" "02:00" "22:00" "23:00"
```

Comment: @R06 You're welcome! Consider to choose one answer and [**mark an answer as accepted**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/371738). That's the way we say _thank you_  on Stack Overflow. From the moment you have +15 reputation you can also [**upvote an answer**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/371738).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the number of characters in `x` needs to be adjusted to at least 3 characters for format string `"%H%M"` to understand that there is a hour in all cases.

```
tmp <- strptime(ifelse(nchar(x) <= 3, paste("0", x), x),"%H%M")
output <- format(tmp,"%H:%M")
output
#[1] "00:30" "02:00" "22:00" "23:00"
```

Comment: doesn't match expected output currently.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to end up with a character string you could bypass `strptime()` with some regex:

```
sub("(\\d{2})", "\\1:", sprintf("%04d", x))
[1] "00:30" "02:00" "22:00" "23:00"
```